# Buffered reader return null (can not get data from SQL server)

Tags: java, android, json, api

I wrote this code to make a connection and I used AsyncTask class  BufferedReader with JSON object and JSON Array, but the bufferedReader return null every time, I tried the API by Fiddler (HTTP debugging server) and it is worked correctly.

```
//class AsyncTask
class GetUserList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String status= null;
    public GetUserList(){
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }
    @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
    protected String doInBackground(String... connUrl){
        HttpURLConnection conn=null;
        BufferedReader reader;
        final URL url;
        int result;
        InputStream in;
        String line;
        try{
            url=new URL(connUrl[0]);
            conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            result = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(result == 200){
                in=new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                line = null;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    status=line;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        JSONObject object;
        String User;
        int i =0;
        if(result!=null){
            try{
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for( i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    User= object.getString("User");
                }//end for
            }//end try
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }//end catch
        }//end if
    }
}
```

Comment: Needs more info. Things like this don't usually just silently fail. There will be a message of some description somewhere, that you ignored or something. What's the logcat say? Are you absolutely sure the response code is 200? Have you even tried debugging your code?

Comment: Scratch all of the above: you never actually connect to the server: read the javadoc (good idea in general): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection() - _It should be noted that a `URLConnection` instance **does not establish the actual network connection on creation**. This will happen only when calling `URLConnection.connect()`._

Comment: yes the response code is 200.
I do not have any error or exception.

Comment: then in this case how can i establish a connection correctly?